# How to remove the dark border which appears after hovering the menu toggle in storefront theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I think this is easy one.How to remove the dark border which appears after hovering the menu toggle in storefront theme in mobile website.
It also appears when i hover on cart in the site header. It really looks ugly. I tried removing by below code but nothing changed.

`.menu-toggle:hover{border: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution myself. It was not the border. It was outline. So i just put this code in style.css.

```
`a:focus,.button:focus,.button.alt:focus,.button.added_to_cart:focus,.button.wc-forward:focus,button:focus,input[type="button"]:focus,input[type="reset"]:focus,input[type="submit"]:focus {
```

outline: none!important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In storefront theme the css it applied on focus which gives reddish border on house hover  -

```
    a:focus, .button:focus, .button.alt:focus, .button.added_to_cart:focus,     .button.wc-forward:focus, button:focus, input[type="button"]:focus,     input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus {
    outline-color: #96588a;
}
```

If you are talking about the same, you can replace it by -

```
a:focus, .button:focus, .button.alt:focus, .button.added_to_cart:focus, .button.wc-forward:focus, button:focus, input[type="button"]:focus, input[type="reset"]:focus, input[type="submit"]:focus  {
    outline-color: black;
}
```

Let me know if you are talking about some other thing.

Comment: Thanks.... I just removed it by this code.                                     outline: none!important;